# Proc Report-Assigning a different format for different rows

Tags: sas, proc-report, proc-format

I have a table that is current laid out in the way I want. The only issue is that when I went to assign the format, it carried over the format for all values. I have a row that should be total, but I'm unsure how to strip the formatting on this row only in proc report:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWu1Z.png)

Want: total line to show no decimals as they are count but the rest of the table to keep same format.

```
    %let gray=CXBFBFBF;
    %let blue=CX13478C;
    %let purple=CXDEDDED;
    title j=c h=10pt f='Calibri' color=black "Table 1-Distribution, CY2016-CY2018";
        options orientation = landscape nonumber nodate leftmargin=0.05in rightmargin=0.05in;
        ods noproctitle noresults escapechar='^';
        ods rtf  file = "path.rtf";
         proc report data= work.temp nowd spanrows  style(report)={width=100%}
            style(header)=[vjust=b font_face = Calibri fontsize=9pt font_weight=bold background=&blue. foreground=white borderrightcolor=black];
            /*List variables in order to select order of columns in table*/
        col ( m_type 
                  ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. vjust=b borderbottomwidth=0.02 }'('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. vjust=b borderbottomwidth=0.01 cellheight=0.20in}Age in Years' d_char_desc)) 
                  ('^S={cellheight=0.20in}Missing Information' 
                  ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' percentage16_1)
                  ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' percentage17_1)
                  ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' percentage18_1))
);
define m_type /order=data group noprint style = [vjust=b just=left cellwidth=0.60in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt];

        define d_char_desc / order=data display  style = [vjust=b just=left cellwidth=0.60in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt]
                         '' style(header)=[vjust=b just=left cellheight=0.18in] style(column)=[vjust=b just=left cellheight=0.35in cellwidth=0.60in];
        define percentage16_1  /display style = [vjust=b just=center  cellwidth=0.60in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         'CY2016' style(header)=[vjust=b just=center cellheight=0.18in] style(column)=[vjust=b just=center cellheight=0.20in cellwidth=0.40in];
        define percentage17_1 /display style = [vjust=b just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         'CY2017' style(header)=[vjust=b just=center cellheight=0.18in] style(column)=[vjust=b just=center cellheight=0.20in cellwidth=0.40in];
        define percentage18_1  /display style = [vjust=b just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         'CY2018' style(header)=[vjust=b just=center cellheight=0.18in] style(column)=[vjust=b just=center cellheight=0.20in cellwidth=0.40in];
compute m_type;    
if m_type = 'm_tot' then
call define (_row_, 'style', 'style=[fontweight=bold background=&gray. font_face=Times]');
endcomp;
run;
ods rtf close;
```

Comment: You can't easily mix formats/analyses within a column using PROC REPORT. Either use PROC TABULATE, or transpose how you want your PROC REPORT.

Comment: Can I not specify an additional call define function for the row only using a format?

Comment: Or, can I create a format since all remaining values  not included in the total value row are less than 100 because they sum to 100 percent?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to explicitly format the numeric values in respective compute blocks.  The numeric value referenced will depend on the `analysis` statistic and the syntax will be *variable.statistic*.

Your data (not shown) appears to be some form of pre-computed aggregation, based on the `m_type = 'm_tot'` source code.  In that case the reference would be something like `percentage16_1.sum` (`sum` is the default `analysis` for numeric variables when there is a grouping specified)

Example:

Summarize some SASHELP.CARS variables and change the format for the **Ford** make.

```
proc report data=sashelp.cars;
  column ( 
    make

    horsepower mpg_city mpg_highway 

    horsepower_custom
    mpg_city_custom
    mpg_highway_custom
  );

  define make / group ;*noprint;

  define horsepower  / analysis noprint mean ;  
  define mpg_city    / analysis noprint mean ;  
  define mpg_highway / analysis noprint mean ;  

  define horsepower_custom / computed style=[textalign=right];
  define mpg_city_custom / computed style=[textalign=right];
  define mpg_highway_custom / computed style=[textalign=right];

  compute horsepower_custom / character length=10;
    if make = 'Ford' 
      then horsepower_custom = put (horsepower.mean, 10.4);
      else horsepower_custom = put (horsepower.mean, 8.1);
  endcomp;

  compute mpg_city_custom / character length=10;
    if make = 'Ford' 
      then mpg_city_custom = put (mpg_city.mean, 10.5);
      else mpg_city_custom = put (mpg_city.mean,  8.2);
  endcomp;

  compute mpg_highway_custom / character length=10;
    if make = 'Ford' 
      then mpg_highway_custom = put (mpg_highway.mean, 10.6);
      else mpg_highway_custom = put (mpg_highway.mean,  8.3);
  endcomp;
run;
```

[image]